# Can't stop timer in python (after and after_cancel)

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I am trying to create a timer in a tkinter GUI that initiates on a start button, and stops on a stop button. I am using *.after* to loop the timer, but I can't correctly integrate *.after_cancel*. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import python modules
import time
import math
from tkinter import *

#Create a root window to work in
root = Tk()
root.title("CNT Synthesis Controller") #title of file

#Create global variables to be stored
global var_status
global current_time
global start_time
current_time = 0

#Create Labels

myLabel_Status_T = Label(root, text="Total time elapsed (hrs:min:sec):")
myLabel_Timer = Label(root, text="00:00:00")

#Locate labels

myLabel_Status_T.grid(row=0, column=0)
myLabel_Timer.grid(row=1, column=0)


#Start button function
def Click_Start():  

    #disable Start Button to prevent re-start
    myButton_Start.config(state=DISABLED)
    
    #initiate time = 0 and start timer
    start_time = time.time()
    global Timer_continue
    Timer_continue = True

    #Timer function
    def Timer():
    
        #determine the amount of time passed since start_time measured
        current_time = int(time.time()-start_time)
        hour = math.floor(current_time/3600)
        minute = math.floor((current_time/60)-(hour*60))
        second = math.floor(current_time-(hour*3600)-(minute*60))       
        #shows time as 00:00:00, i.e. adding in the zeroes where needed
        if hour<10:
            hour=str("0"+str(hour))
        else:
            hour=str(hour)
        if minute<10:
            minute=str("0"+str(minute))
        else:
            minute=str(minute)
        if second<10:
              second=str("0"+str(second))
        else:
              second=str(second)
        #print the time to the label myLabel_Timer
        myLabel_Timer.config(text= hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second)
        #after 1000 ms repeat the Timer function
        #while (myButton_Stop['state'] != tk.DISABLED):

        #Timer_Object=myLabel_Timer.after(1000,Timer)
        if Timer_continue == True:
           root.after(1000,Timer)
        if Timer_continue == False:
           root.after_cancel(Timer)
    
    Timer()

#Stop button function
def Click_Stop():  
    Timer_continue = False
    #disable Stop Button to prevent re-use until program is reset
    myButton_Stop.config(state=DISABLED)    



#Create Buttons
myButton_Start = Button(root,text="Start CNT Synthesis", padx=40, pady=20, fg="white", bg="green", command=Click_Start)
myButton_Stop = Button(root,text="Stop CNT Synthesis", padx=40, pady=20, fg="white", bg="red", command=Click_Stop)
#Locate buttons
myButton_Start.grid(row=2, column=0)
myButton_Stop.grid(row=2, column=1)




root.mainloop()
```

####---------------------------------------------------------------------Required added text to make the question 'long enough'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------##########

Comment: Please don't add extra characters to work around system requirements.  Those requirements exist for a reason. Also, please explain what "I can't correctly integrate .after_cancel" means. Why can't you? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the ID returned by `.after()` and use it in `.after_cancel()` to stop the timer inside `Click_Stop()` function:

```py
#import python modules
import time
from tkinter import *

#Create a root window to work in
root = Tk()
root.title("CNT Synthesis Controller") #title of file

#Create Labels
myLabel_Status_T = Label(root, text="Total time elapsed (hrs:min:sec):")
myLabel_Timer = Label(root, text="00:00:00")

#Locate labels
myLabel_Status_T.grid(row=0, column=0)
myLabel_Timer.grid(row=1, column=0)

Timer_id = None  # used to store the ID returned by .after()

#Start button function
def Click_Start():  
    #disable Start Button to prevent re-start
    myButton_Start.config(state=DISABLED)
    #enable Stop Button
    myButton_Stop.config(state=NORMAL)
    
    #save the start timer
    start_time = time.time()

    #Timer function
    def Timer():
        global Timer_id
    
        #determine the amount of time passed since start_time measured
        elapsed = int(time.time()-start_time)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(elapsed, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        myLabel_Timer.config(text=f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}")

        #after 1000 ms repeat the Timer function
        Timer_id = root.after(1000,Timer) # save the after ID
    
    Timer()

#Stop button function
def Click_Stop():
    if Timer_id:
        root.after_cancel(Timer_id) # cancel the scheduled task
    #disable Stop Button to prevent re-use until program is reset
    myButton_Stop.config(state=DISABLED)  
    #enable Start Button
    myButton_Start.config(state=NORMAL)  

#Create Buttons
myButton_Start = Button(root,text="Start CNT Synthesis", padx=40, pady=20,
                        fg="white", bg="green", command=Click_Start)
myButton_Stop = Button(root,text="Stop CNT Synthesis", padx=40, pady=20,
                       fg="white", bg="red", command=Click_Stop, state=DISABLED) # disable stop button initially
#Locate buttons
myButton_Start.grid(row=2, column=0)
myButton_Stop.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Miss the global statement:

```
def Click_Stop():
    global Timer_continue
    Timer_continue = False
```

Comment: I have added in the global statement in the Click_Stop definition but the timer still won't stop